# Run a method in Observer after Billing Information

Tags: checkout, quote, billing

I have this in config.xml

```
<global>
    <events>
        <sales_quote_save_after>
            <observers>
                <save_after>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Practice_Payment_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>saveQuoteAfter</method>
                </save_after>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_save_after>
        .
        .
```

And my Observer.php

```
public function saveQuoteAfter($evt){
    $quote = $evt->getQuote();

    // $post variable is checkbox in the Billing Information
    $post = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getPost();

    if(isset($post['custom']['consultancyservice'])){
        $var = $post['custom']['consultancyservice'];
        $quote->setConsultancyservice($var);
    } else {
        $var = 'false';
        $quote->setConsultancyservice($var);
    }
    $model = Mage::getModel('custom/custom_quote');
    $model->deteleByQuote($quote->getId(),'consultancyservice');
    $model->setQuoteId($quote->getId());
    $model->setKey('consultancyservice');
    $model->setValue($var);
    $model->save();
}
```

`$post` is variable is checkbox in the Billing Information

This updates the value in the database. But whenever I go beyond 'Billing Information' it resets. Maybe because `sales_quote_save_after` runs at all steps in the checkout?

I have also tried `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_savebilling` and `controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_savebilling` but they are not working.

Thanks to anyone who can help!!

Comment: Each step in the checkout has a variable indicating the step (not able to check the name at the moment). Filter the event based upon that variable. Also the reason why your event should be in the frontend space only. In the admin this will be different.

Answer (score 1):

Hi instead of using  `sales_quote_save_after` use

```
sales_quote_address_save_after or sales_quote_address_save_before
```

and youobserver code is wroong

```
public function saveQuoteAfter($observer){
    /* change here */
$addressObject=$observer->getEvent()->getQuoteAddress();


    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteAddress()->getQuote();

    // $post variable is checkbox in the Billing Information
    $post = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getPost();

    if(isset($post['custom']['consultancyservice'])){
        $var = $post['custom']['consultancyservice'];
        $quote->setConsultancyservice($var);
    } else {
        $var = 'false';
        $quote->setConsultancyservice($var);
    }
    $model = Mage::getModel('custom/custom_quote');
    $model->deteleByQuote($quote->getId(),'consultancyservice');
    $model->setQuoteId($quote->getId());
    $model->setKey('consultancyservice');
    $model->setValue($var);
    $model->save();
}
```

Comment: Both are giving this error: `Call to a member function functionnamehere() on a non-object`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It works `sales_quote_save_after` because it updates the value after Billing Information, but resets back to 'false' once I move on..